# PHP with DATE_ADD did not work

Tags: php

Thanks to everybody who gave me some advice and answers. As I'm so new to this, I must appologize for some poor questions and technical terms. I decided to use DREAMWEAVER to finish this and still have some problems.
These are the changes that I made:

1.Change 'expiry_date' field to NULL because when I submit the form with 'NOT NULL' it didn't get through (`expiry_date` DATE NULL ,).

2.This is the code that I have

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) 
{
    $template = "INSERT INTO expirydate_table "
              . "(firstname, lastname, email, password, "
              . "signup_date, expiry_date) "
              . "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)";

    $insertSQL = sprintf(
        $template,
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['lastname'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['signup_date'], "date"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['expiry_date'], "date")
    );
```

3.The form with the hidden fileds of 'signup_date' and 'expiry_date'

```
<input type="hidden" name="signup_date" value="<?php echo $row_RecRegister3['NOW()']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="expiry_date" value="<?php echo $row_RecRegister3['DATE_ADD(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY))']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
```

Result:

1. I can submit the form and `signup_date` displays in database.
2. `expiry_date` did not show any data.

Question:

1. Is there any function to make it work or replace 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'?

Answer (score 0):

According to your example above:

- Your form uses as signup_date = `NOW()` (the MySQL function) and the expiry date is 30 days after that.
- Your PHP code snippet is the one that creates the insert statement for MySQL.

You do not need to send the signup_date and expiry date through your form. All you have to do is set it up in your insert statement.

So your form is going to be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
```

and your PHP

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) 
{
    $template = "INSERT INTO expirydate_table "
              . "(firstname, lastname, email, password, "
              . "signup_date, expiry_date) "
              . "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)";

    $now     = new DateTime();
    $signup  = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $future  = $now->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
    $expiry  = $future->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $insertSQL = sprintf(
        $template,
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['lastname'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
        $signup,
        $expiry
    );
}
```

Comment: I found this after editing:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add() on line 49
which is --
$future  = $now->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
Please help me solve this! Thank you so much.

Comment: @patmuumai It could be that you are not using php 5.3 or higher. Have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php. There are alternatives with mktime, time and date that you can use to calculate the signup and expiry dates.